# how to make sure all the images in correct orientation?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

my app is simple.

uploading a photo to firebase storage (a profile photo).
then when someone opens the profile. I call the photo from firebase storage.

the problem:

after I uploading a photo to firebase storage, from gallery that I captured using my smartphone, when I am calling it back, the photo got rotated 90 degree in the activity.
but if I uploaded a photo to firebase from my gallery but from another source like (whatsapp) ,
when I call it back. the photo appears in the correct orientation.

any ideas how to solve this problem?

Updated: how i download the photo

```
        final StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("SomeReference");

        try {
            final File localFile = File.createTempFile("somephoto", "jpg");
            ref.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    System.out.println("onSuccess ");
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    viewHolder.imageViewFriendPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("onFailure " + e.getMessage());

                }
            });

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Sounds like two components disagree on whether the EXIF orientation/rotation metadata is to be considered. Make sure that you treat this consistently (especially when scaling images, that's a common source of "losing"/ignoring that information).

Comment: You have uploaded or downloaded the file in the wrong way. A way in which the orientation information which is in the file was removed. But as you did not tell how you uploaded... or downloaded...

Comment: @JoachimSauer i will try

Comment: @blackapps i don't think there is a problem in uploading, because when i open the firebase console and look at the photos, i see them in the correct orientation ( all of them ).
I think there is a problem in downloading
i will edit the post to include the code

Comment: You let BitmapFactory.decodeFile() download from firebase. And BitmapFactory ignores orientation info.

Comment: @blackapps ok, thanks for the info, is there a way to fix it ? or should i found someway else to download the photo ?

Comment: If you dont wanna save to file and you only want a bitmap then download twice. The second time using ExifInterface which will give you the orientation. Then rotate your bitmap accordingly. You can put all in one function.

Comment: @blackapps i will try this approach, thank you man.